# Color specific filenames (not extensions) in `ls` output like Makefile or CMakeLists.txt

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, colors

I am currently working on a C++ project. I am using CMake as a build system and I would love to have all the CMake related files (like `CMakeLists.txt`) colored differently in the `ls` command output. This way I could easily distinguish them from the source code files.

I was trying to both use `dircolors` and edit directly `$LS_COLORS` env var. I failed in both cases. It seems that those solutions only provide a way to color either some Linux specific files (eg. links) or selected extensions.

To sum it up, this is what I did:

```
OLD_LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS # Backup
export LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}CMakeLists.txt=00;36:" # Adding it at the beginning of the list also fails
ls # No colors at all
export LS_COLORS=$OLD_LS_COLORS # Cleanup
dircolors -p > ~/.dir_colors
echo "CMakeLists.txt 01;33" >> ~/.dir_colors
eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors` # Throws "unrecognized keyword CMakeLists.txt"
```

Workaround for my problem would be to color the source files (`.hxx`, `.cxx`) instead but I would like to stick with coloring CMake files only. On the other hand I could just color `.txt` and `.cmake` files but then all the text files would be colored in such fashion.

Coloring a Makefile (a file with no extension) in `ls` output would be a nice bonus.

I am using Debian 9 with `bash` 4.4.12 and `ls` 8.26.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with ls.

```
*Makefile       38;5;155
*CMakeLists.txt 48;5;89;38;5;197;1;3;4;7
```

See https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/blob/master/LS_COLORS

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that with `ls` directly. (But it might be...)

My Idea would be, to pipe the output of `ls` to sed, which can color it's regex matches.

There is a nice snippet which does this: https://github.com/kepkin/dev-shell-essentials/blob/master/highlight.sh

You could write a chain of pipes which matches all cmake files:
`ls | highlight blue CMakeLists.txt | highlight blue foobar.baz ...` (and create an alias for this)

But this is of course a workaround.

My personal choice would be to use out-of-source builds and keep the cmake files seperated to a certain degree. But this is not an answer to your question and might not be possible in your project structure...